# How can I assign web scraping outputs to an array using python?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I would like to execute this and get all of the text from the title and href attributes. The code runs, and I do get all of the needed data, but I would like to assign the outputs to an array and when I attempt to assign this just gives me the last instance of the attributes being true in the HTML.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

r = urllib.urlopen('http://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?map=hsa05215&show_description=show').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup((r), "lxml")
for area in soup.find_all('area', href=True):
    print area['href']
for area in soup.find_all('area', title=True):
    print area['title']
```

If it helps, I'm doing this because I will create a list with the data later. I'm just beginning to learn, so extra explanations are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use l[ist comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
links = [area['href'] for area in soup.find_all('area', href=True)]
titles = [area['title'] for area in soup.find_all('area', title=True)]
```